# Mettre du beurre dans les épinards

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

After doing some light research I found idiomatic translations such as

*we could use the extra*

*to grease the wheels*

*make lemons into lemonade*

*put butter on your bread*

I'm somewhat confused. I gather that *mettre du beurre dans les épinards* is an idiom referring to jimprovement or success but I'm finding it difficult to get more clarity.

Comment: The closest of your propositions would be "use the extra". I understand "grease the wheels" as facilitating a specific situation, "lemons into lemonade" as dealing with unplanned events and "butter on the bread" as flattering someone. Here it's really about a little extra (usually money) improving your life conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Improvement, it's an expression to express a amelioration of your life situation.

"Mettre du beurre dans les épinards" signifie que l'on améliore ses conditions de vie, et en général dans le domaine financier. En fait, le beurre symbolise la facilité et la simplicité alors que les épinards connoteraient plutôt une situation délicate, voire des ennuis. [source](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/222/mettre-du-beurre-dans-les-epinards/)

Comment: Je ne pense qu'il y ait besoin de symbolique ici, l’expression veut littérairement dire "(Avoir les moyens de) mettre du beurre dans les épinard". En paraphrasant, "avoir les moyens d'améliorer l'ordinaire".

Comment: ...parce que tout est meilleur avec du beurre, mais il n'est pas indispensable.

Comment: Le beurre symbolise aussi l'aisance de vie (ou financière). Voir : faire son beurre. Le beurre et l'argent du beurre. On retrouve cela aussi dans l'expression anglaise "guns versus butter" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns_versus_butter_model.

Answer (score 1):

Very few people like spinach, especially kids. So, butter helps, like in the expression "faire passer la pillule "?!

Comment: *Faire passer la pilule* is similar in English.  Could you elaborate on how this is different from other answers, which all say butter helps? Merci et bienvenue sur French Language SE.

Answer (score 0):

La meilleure façon de bien intégrer cette expression serait d'acheter des épinards au supermarché et de les faire cuire avec et sans beurre. Ou plus généralement avec et sans matière grasse - j'utilise généralement un fond d'huile et de la crème fraîche à la fin.

Creamed wilted spinach is super easy to cook. Voilà [une recette d'épinards au beurre](https://www.cuisineactuelle.fr/recettes/poelee-d-epinards-frais-au-beurre-171967).

Après dégustation, le sens de l'expression sera bien plus clair! Selon moi, il n'y a pas de symbolique, c'est au contraire une expression très concrète. Comme "la fin des haricots".

Comment: Personnellement, j'achète les épinards chez le maraîcher, certainement pas au supermarché.

Comment: Je crois pas que l'idiom dans cette phrase signifie cuisinier : `Et bien que ces derniers soient également tributaires de certaines conditions de déblocage, ils peuvent mettre un peu de beurre dans les épinards et donner un coup de fouet à votre bankroll.`